# Date-field gets deleted on creation of bibliography

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, citing, natbib

My bibliography doesn't behave as expected: all citations don't have dates in the final document. I believe that is caused by an error when creating the `.bbl`-file: it seems, as the `date` field is deleted somewhere in that process.

I use `natbib` with `plainnat`-style. I created a minimal test file, which shows the behaviour and attached it below.

Can someone help me with this?

My `.bib`-file looks like the following:

```
@article{Burkhardt2006,
  title = {Who Is Attracted to Carsharing?},
  volume = {1986},
  issn = {0361-1981},
  url = {http://trrjournalonline.trb.org/doi/10.3141/1986-15},
  doi = {10.3141/1986-15},
  timestamp = {2015-07-20 15:34:50},
  journaltitle = {Transportation Research Record: Journal of the Transportation Research Board},
  shortjournal = {Transp. Res. Rec. J. Transp. Res. Board},
  author = {Burkhardt, Jon and Millard-Ball, Adam},
  urldate = {2015-07-20},
  date = {2006-01},
  pages = {98--105},
  langid = {english}
}
```

My test-file:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}    

\begin{document}
    Cite this \citep{Burkhardt2006}

    \bibliography{bib.bib}
\end{document}
```

The output `.bbl`- and `pdf`-file:

```
\begin{thebibliography}{1}
\providecommand{\natexlab}[1]{#1}
\providecommand{\url}[1]{\texttt{#1}}
\expandafter\ifx\csname urlstyle\endcsname\relax
  \providecommand{\doi}[1]{doi: #1}\else
  \providecommand{\doi}{doi: \begingroup \urlstyle{rm}\Url}\fi

\bibitem[Burkhardt and Millard-Ball()]{Burkhardt2006}
Jon Burkhardt and Adam Millard-Ball.
\newblock Who is attracted to carsharing?
\newblock 1986:\penalty0 98--105.
\newblock ISSN 0361-1981.
\newblock \doi{10.3141/1986-15}.
\newblock URL \url{http://trrjournalonline.trb.org/doi/10.3141/1986-15}.

\end{thebibliography}
```

[image]

[Here](https://owncloud.tu-berlin.de/public.php?service=files&t=c436c832f6a5127ad1244372686f3e97) is everything as a ZIP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using field names in the `.bib` which require Biblatex,  but are then using BibTeX only to compile. BibTeX/`natbib`/etc. don't know anything about `date` or `journaltitle`.

You need to either

- use Biblatex

or

- correct the `.bib` file to use traditional BibTeX fields e.g. `journal`, `year`, `month`, `day` etc.

Comment: Solved it! I actually use [zotero](https://www.zotero.org/) and export my bib from there. I guess I've somehow changed the default export option. Thanks!